# Enzyme/Mocha: How to test a react component function by firing an onChange event from a child component

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm using enzyme/mocha to test my react component.

I have a parent component  which I am testing.

```
let wrapper = mount(<Parent />);
```

and this parent has a child component in it's render function

```
render: function() {
    <Child onChange={this.foo} />
},
foo: function() {
    console.log("I was called");
}
```

I would like the child's onChange function to fire so that I can test my parents foo function.

So far, I have found no way to do this - I've read about sinon and stubbing but that's mostly about intercepting functions and not firing them.

The following test

```
shallow(<Parent />).instance().foo();
```

is a weak test because it doesn't test the line of code connecting my child and parent, and in case I haven't written a unit test for my child, it doesn't test the child's onChange functionality either. IMHO - If breaking up my components to parents/children means less testability - then something is wrong with this framework

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you test the `foo()` method in the parent tests, and the child's ability to trigger `props.onChange()` (using `sinon.spy()`) in the child tests, then IMO you don't need to test that React can call `this.foo` given that the child calls `props.onChange`. Just like you don't need to test that React calls `render()` when state changes or `componentWillReceiveProps()` when props change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that I do in a lot of my tests.  The method that I've found that works best for me is to manually invoke the child component's `onChange` handler, and make your assertions based on the behavior you expect to happen as a result.

So let's say you have a Parent component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child';

export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onChange={this.foo} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    foo() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

The `onChange` prop passed to child will log the string 'bar' when invoked.  This is the behavior we want to test.  To do this, we'll need to take the following steps:

1. Stub `console.log` using your mocking library of choice (I'll be using Sinon for this example)
2. Create a shallow instance of the Parent component, and obtain a reference to its Child.
3. Manually invoke the Child's `onChange` prop.
4. Assert that `console.log` was called once, and with a single argument: 'bar'

And here is how I would do that (using mocha and chai):

```
import Foo from './foo';

import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

import sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';

describe('Foo', () => {
    let renderedElement;

    function renderComponent() {
        const componentElement = React.createElement(Foo);

        renderedElement = shallow(componentElement);
    }

    before(() => {
        chai.use(sinonChai);
    });

    it('should log the string "bar" when the child component is changed', () => {
        //step 1
        sinon.stub(console, 'log');

        //step 2
        renderComponent();
        const childComponent = renderedElement.props().children;

        //step 3
        childComponent.props.onChange();

        //step 4
        expect(console.log).to.have.callCount(1);
        expect(console.log).to.be.calledWith('bar');

        //clean up
        console.log.restore();
    });
});
```

The reason I like this approach is because it's testing component **behavior** as opposed to simply testing that it was passed a function as a prop that happens to be equal to another function.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your tests into parts. For example...

Firstly, test that the expected function was passed to your child component:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const actual = shallow(<Parent />);
const expected = <Child onChange={actual.instance().foo} />

expect(actual.matchesElement(expected)).true;
```

I like to use the simple `matchesElement` approach above when there is little being rendered in the Component I am testing, but you could also use a `find` selector to find the `Child` instance and then test it.

Then test your foo function seperately:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const actual = shallow(<Parent />).instance().foo();
const expected = 'expected return of foo'

expect(actual).equals(expected);
```

You can test your `Child` component separately and how it handles it's `onChange` prop.

Some of the enzyme API's being used here:

- [.instance()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.md)
- [.matchesElement(node)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/matchesElement.md)

Also look at:

- [.containsMatchingElement(node)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsMatchingElement.md)
- [.find(selector)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.md)

Comment: This isn't a bad idea but in general its not testing functionality, its comparing strings. What's the difference between matches and simple checking that the render function wasn't changed each commit? Also, Parent contains about 10 components, and I was simplifying the question.

Comment: See my comment below the example: for any complex renders it's better to use the `find` api to locate the child and assert it has been decorated as expected.